# Using _document.js and _app.js for the meta information (Next JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been working on my Next JS app with React.

Basically I have the ff codes on my `index.js` file:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

As you can see here I've added a Bootstrap CDN and a meta information.

And then inside my `_app.js` I've added my `meta viewport`:

```
import Head from "next/head";

function MyApp() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

When I run `npm run dev`, I got the error here:

```
Warning: Invalid DOM property `charset`. Did you mean `charSet`?
    at meta
    at head
    at Head (C:\Users\D\Desktop\multiblog\frontend\.next\server\pages\_document.js:705:5)
```

Am I doing this right? separating my meta information and link tag to my `index.js`?

What I want is to load all of my meta tags once the pages loads first?

Any idea?

Comment: Please see what our Prophet Dan Abramov says about it - [link1](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11160#issuecomment-335215133), [link2](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10863)

Comment: React doesn't accept `charset`, you need to use `charSet` instead.